# Check for person prior to save

Tags: validation, display-name

I have a SharePoint form (not in InfoPath) that can be created by numerous personnel.  In order for us to accept a request, the form must have acceptance from two people--one inside our shop, one outside.  I want to create a validation in the column of "OPS Support Decision" that requires "accepted"--a drop down, if the current user belongs to OPS.  If the form is being created by someone outside of OPS, then the "Element Support Decision" would require "accepted"--a drop down as well, if the user is outside of OPS.  I am willing to write the code, but this certainly is not like excel...and I am lost!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.  There is a function is SPServices that will allow you to check if a user belongs to a certain permissions group.  You can check this on DocReady then apply your logic to the form to set the value of the dropdowns, hide/show, or whatever logic you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/js/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    isGroupMember("Your User Group", function(result){
        if(result){

            //do your ddl logic here or write a separate function to call here
        }
    });
});


function isGroupMember(groupName, callback)
{
    $().SPServices({
          operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
          userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
          async: true,
          completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

          callback( !!($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='" + groupName + "']").length) ); /* returns bool */
          }
    });
};

</script>
```